# how to work the loop in Qt GUI application and display the qimage

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, image-processing

I am new to Qt and OpenCV and need help with the following problem.

I am developing a code to count vehicles coming to a park. Pre-obtained input video is used to develop the algorithm. I have chosen a Qt widget application with OpenCV for this. Currently when compiling, the loop below is skipped.

```
for( ; contour != 0; contour = contour->h_next ) 

                {
                    bndRect = cvBoundingRect(contour, 0);

                    ui->txtXYnew->appendPlainText("one contour");
                    pt1.x = bndRect.x;
                    pt1.y = bndRect.y;
                    pt2.x = bndRect.x + bndRect.width;
                    pt2.y = bndRect.y + bndRect.height;

                    printf("--------------------\n");
                 cvRectangle(newImage, pt1, pt2, CV_RGB(255,0,0), 1); 
                 }
```

and the compilation moves  to the next section. Why is that, am I using the timer function wrong ? (I have tested this in a console application and it worked fine both Qt and Visual Studio).

I have used two labels, one to display the input frame, and the second for the processed frame. Currently in the processed frame a black frame is shown. but it should show the processed frame with rectangles drawn around contours.

Is there any way to correct this code ? Below is the complete code.

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include  <QtCore>
#include  <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
using namespace cv;

using namespace std;

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :QDialog(parent), ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
ui->setupUi(this);

inputMovie = cvCaptureFromAVI("E:\\pk.avi");
if (!inputMovie){
   ui->txtXYnew->appendPlainText("error video");
   return;
}


tmrTimer=new QTimer(this);
connect(tmrTimer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(processedframesandudateGUI()));
tmrTimer->start(25);


}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Dialog::~Dialog()
{
delete ui;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void Dialog::processedframesandudateGUI(){

    CvRect bndRect = cvRect(0,0,0,0);

    CvPoint pt1, pt2;


    CvSize imgSize;
    imgSize.width = 540;
    imgSize.height = 432;
greyImage = cvCreateImage( imgSize, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
movingAverage = cvCreateImage( imgSize, IPL_DEPTH_32F, 3);
colourImage = cvQueryFrame(inputMovie);


bool first = true;


        if(!colourImage)
           { ui->txtXYnew->appendPlainText("no frames");
            return;}

        if(first)
                {
                        difference = cvCloneImage(colourImage);
                        temp = cvCloneImage(colourImage);
                        cvConvertScale(colourImage, movingAverage, 1.0, 0.0);

                    first = false;
                }

        cvConvertScale(movingAverage, temp, 1.0, 0.0);
        cvAbsDiff(colourImage,temp,difference);


        cvCvtColor(difference, greyImage, CV_RGB2GRAY);

        cvThreshold(greyImage,greyImage, 70, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);


        newImage = cvCloneImage(colourImage);

        cvDilate(greyImage, greyImage, 0, 18);
        cvErode(greyImage, greyImage, 0, 10);

       CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
       CvSeq* contour = 0;

         ui->txtXYnew->appendPlainText("contour");
         printf("******\n");

  cvFindContours( greyImage, storage, &contour, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);


              for( ; contour != 0; contour = contour->h_next )

                {
                    bndRect = cvBoundingRect(contour, 0);

                    ui->txtXYnew->appendPlainText("one contour");
                    pt1.x = bndRect.x;
                    pt1.y = bndRect.y;
                    pt2.x = bndRect.x + bndRect.width;
                    pt2.y = bndRect.y + bndRect.height;

                    printf("--------------------\n");
                 cvRectangle(newImage, pt1, pt2, CV_RGB(255,0,0), 1);


                }

     printf("here\n");

    cvCvtColor(colourImage, colourImage, CV_BGR2RGB);
    QImage qimgOriginal((uchar*)colourImage->imageData,colourImage->width, colourImage->height, colourImage->widthStep, QImage::Format_RGB888);
    QImage qimgProcessed((uchar*)newImage->imageData,newImage->width, newImage->height, newImage->widthStep, QImage::Format_RGB888);

    ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qimgOriginal));
    ui->label->resize(ui->label->pixmap()->size());
    ui->txtXYnew->appendPlainText("one frame");

    ui->label_2->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qimgProcessed));
    ui->label_2->resize(ui->label_2->pixmap()->size());

    cvReleaseImage(&temp);
    cvReleaseImage(&difference);
    cvReleaseImage(&greyImage);
    cvReleaseImage(&movingAverage);


}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

if(tmrTimer->isActive()==true)
{
    tmrTimer->stop();
    ui->pushButton->setText("resume");
}
else
{
    tmrTimer->start(25);
    ui->pushButton->setText("pause");
}
}
```

---

---

Below is shown the dialog.h (header file) code.

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Dialog : public QDialog
{
Q_OBJECT


public:
explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
~Dialog();


public slots:
void processedframesandudateGUI();

private slots:

void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
Ui::Dialog *ui;

QImage qimgOriginal;
QImage qimgProcessed;

IplImage* greyImage ;
IplImage* colourImage;
IplImage* newImage;
IplImage* movingAverage ;
IplImage* difference;
IplImage* temp;
CvCapture* inputMovie;
QTimer *tmrTimer;



};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

edit:

i still ddn't found any luck. i fallowed the method described by Chernobyl and it also skipped the loop. can anybody solve this. i am using Qt 5.3.1 for Windows 32-bit with MinGW and this code compiles perfectly on console application.any support guys. still waiting for a answer.

Comment: In the qimgProcessed change QImage::Format_RGB888 to QImage::Format_Indexed8. It works?

Comment: no sir it did not..i tried it already. here i have to display the colour image with a red rectangle drawn around the moving vehicles. so i guess i have to go with RGB888. i guess this helps you.any sugesstions on why that loop skiped. i am not much familiar with the qt interface. thanx for your interest in my problem..

Comment: I work in Qt+ opencv too, but I use  another opencv elements for doing similar thing and I can get you one my code snippet which perfectly works on my computer but in my code I don't use CvMemStorage, CvSeq (my OpenCV version - 2.4.9) etc. Do you want this?

Comment: that would be great sir.if you have a working one plz provide it. i didn't develop this code on my one. so i can always change this.i am familiar with both c and c++ api's in opencv. (little c++).only problem is that i am new to qt interface. thanx again for your interest.( i use opencv version 2.4.8).sir u can post here or here is my email. dazzirulz@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

In your code you intializes 'contour' with

{ CvSeq* contour = 0; }

to zero. This is followed by the loop with the condition 'contour != 0;'

{ for( ; contour != 0; contour = contour->h_next ) }

This, the compiler recognizes that the condition to excecute the loop body will never fullfilled and skips the loop body.

Comment: sir i have compiled my code in both qt and visual studio console applications and it delivered the desired output. so how can this condition be skipped. thanx for your suggestions and interest. can you kindly suggest a method to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that all other code is normal and works good, so I show my loop, I try adapt my code to your  but I don't so sure.

```
//this is our containers
        std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours; // Vector for storing contour
        std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
        cv::Rect rect;

//now we try to find contours on the grayscale image
        findContours( greyImage, contours, hierarchy,CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );

        for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ ) // iterate through each contour.
         {
          double a = contourArea( contours[i],false);  //  Find the area of contour

          if(a > 30)//you can delete this lines if you don't want search big contours
          {
          rect = boundingRect(contours[i]); // Find the bounding rectangle 
          cv::Point2f centerCircle;
          float rad;
          cv::minEnclosingCircle(contours[i],centerCircle,rad);//search circle
          cv::rectangle(newImage, rect,  cv::Scalar(255,0,0),1, 8,0);//draw rect
          cv::circle(newImage, centerCircle,rad,  cv::Scalar(255,0,0),1, 8,0);//draw circle

         }
         }
```

Set picture but this is not so useful

```
cv::cvtColor(frame,frame,CV_BGR2RGB);
cv::resize(frame,frame,cv::Size2i(ui->label->geometry().width(),ui->label->geometry().height()));
QImage image1((uchar*)frame.data,frame.cols,frame.rows,frame.step,QImage::Format_RGB888);
QPixmap px1(QPixmap::fromImage(image1));
ui->label_2->setPixmap(px1);
```

Comment: sir thanx for the quick reply. i compiled your code and added two printf lines one inside the for loop and one inside the if condition. sadly code does not enter to the for loop and it skip that part and move to the next section printing "here".